# Powershell, Shared Access Database

Tags: powershell, ms-access, powershell-2.0

I'm currently working on a tool at work. At user logon a script will run to create an XML document with computer information. It then initiates another script to edit the database with that information.

This works perfectly if used on my own computer. It also works on a coworkers when I remote in and run it manually. However. I've come to believe that it is because it's locking the database whenever it's attempting to update the database.

I want multiple machines to be able to write to it. Is this possible? How?

Keep in mind, must work with PowerShell 2.0.

```
$DataBaseFilePath = "\\SomeServer\SomeShare\SomeFolder\..."

$adOpenDynamic = 2
$adLockPessimistic = -1

$Connection = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Connection
$RecordSet = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Recordset

$Connection.Open("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = $($DataBaseFilePath)")

$RecordSet.Open("SELECT * FROM Clients WHERE ComputerName = '$($Env:COMPUTERNAME)'",
$Connection, $adOpenDynamic, $adLockPessimistic)
```

Comment: "*I wrote this script and it works perfectly when I run it, and it works on a coworker's computer*" - ok, great. and?  I guess your unasked question is about running it at the same time, and the easy answer is: don't do that. Dump the XML files to a shared folder, have one script on one machine which reads those into the database...?

Comment: If you want to have shared (concurrent) write a access to a database, use a proper database server, not an Access file. At which point creating an XML file first becomes a rather useless operation.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to specify what the actual problem is. Do you get an error message? Does the script hang? ...?

Comment: I edited it to reflect what I want. But it was answered already, thanks.